# Doxygen doesn't work with 2D arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, doxygen

I'm trying to use Doxygen with my C# code and I have properties that return values that are in an 2D array. (it's not very pretty, sorry)

```
public double V00 => values[0, 0];
public double V01 => values[0, 1];
public double V02 => values[0, 2];
public double V03 => values[0, 3];
public double V10 => values[1, 0];
```

The problem is that `Doxygen` parses it very veridly and doesn't seem to understand that it's a 2D array. It stops at the `,` and adds a `double` at the begining of the next line.

```
double double V01 => values[0;
double double double V02 => values[0;
double double double double V03 => values[0;
double double double double double V10 => values[1;
```

I'm using C# 9.0 and Doxygen 1.8.17.

Does someone knows if there's a way to fix that ? Or should I just change my code to work around this ?

Comment: Looks like that bug's [been around since 2015](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5741). I'd drop a comment on that issue to bump it, but I wouldn't hold my breath on it being fixed any time soon. Jagged arrays are often more efficient in C#, anyway

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll comment on it ! I guess I have to change my code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the version 1.8.17 is not very old (December 2019) it looks to me that the results with the version 1.9.1 look better:

```
double  V00 [get]
double  V01 [get]
double  V02 [get]
double  V03 [get]
double  V10 [get]
```

I used as input file:

```
public double V00 => values[0, 0];
public double V01 => values[0, 1];
public double V02 => values[0, 2];
public double V03 => values[0, 3];
public double V10 => values[1, 0];
```

and as Doxyfile:

```
EXTRACT_ALL=YES
```

Otherwise please add a complete example.